# Why does "sudo ls ~" show the contents of /home/username rather than /root?

Tags: sudo, users, ls, root

When I'm logged in as *`username`*, why does

```
sudo ls ~
```

show me the contents of `/home/username` rather than `/root`? I thought that `sudo` executes a command as root, in which case `~` would represent `/root`.

**more explanation:**

Additionally, if I run the `su` command, and then run `ls ~`, I am shown contents of `/root`. So I thought doing that was equivalent to `sudo ls ~`.

As another example, some commands with a `--user` flag will interpret the user to be root when run as `sudo`. For example, `pip install --user packagename` will install to a directory within  `/home/username`, while `sudo pip install --user packagename`  will install to a directory within `/root`. Note that it is not advised to run the last command, I'm just using it to show the functionality I'm describing.

Comment: I suppose this answer might give you the clue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1660054/11639109

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shell expands `~` before running `sudo`; you can see this in action with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ sudo ls ~
+ sudo ls /home/skitt
```

which shows that the command actually run already has the home directory expanded, using the current user at the time of the expansion.

To see the target user’s home directory, you have to defer the [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html):

```
sudo bash -c 'ls ~'
```

Comment: How to do this with `-u`? I tried `sudo -u otheruser bash -c 'ls ~'`, but it still lists my own home directory.

Comment: @not2savvy `-u` “just works” for me, I’m not sure what might be different in your case.

Comment: I found out that it does work in exactly the same way on every *nix flavor. On macOS, which is BSD Unix based, the command requires option `-i` (interactive shell) to be added, which I suppose causes the shell to establish the destination user environment. This also works under Ubuntu, so I propose that the suggested solution be `sudo bash -i -c 'ls ~'`